# VASP GW+SOC band structure calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, spin-orbit-coupling, gw-bse

How may I carry out GW+SOC a band structure calculation using VASP? Could anyone familiar describe it step-by-step? I could not find any info regarding this on the VASP wiki.

Comment: +1 welcome to our new community, and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future!!!

Answer (score 5):

Here I show the typical calculation flow of GW in VASP:

1. a DFT ground-state calculation.
2. obtain DFT virtual orbitals
3. GW calculation including LWANNIER90 TAG
4. Compute Wannier functions and Obtain bandstructure by Wannier interpolation.

PS1: use `POTCAR` like [`XXX_GW`].

PS2: If you want to include spin-orbit coupling, just add the following tags:

```
LSORBIT=.TRUE.  
SAXIS= 0 0 1  
ISYM=0
```

[See here for more information.](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Bandstructure_of_Si_in_GW_(VASP2WANNIER90))

Comment: +1. Is there anything you can say about SOC though? Also I made some minor edits which you may want to look at.

Comment: @NikeDattani  I have fixed that :).

Comment: Thanks @Jack for the nice answer. I just have one question. I'm not very familiar with the WANNIER90. what are some advantages of this code for this type of calculation and can't you have GW+SOC band structure calculation without using it?

Comment: @Chris It is recommended by VASP developers, you need to familiarize that.

Comment: @Chris you might want to ask about advantages of Wannier90 in a separate post.